# What is the last value of b which breaks the loop? ( Is it -1 if I am not wrong?? )

Tags: java

```
for (int b = 3; b >= 0; b--) {
    System.out.println("");

    for (int a = 0; a <= b; a++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

It is an asterisk pattern, I understand this code and as per my understanding that last value of b should be -1 so that the final outer loop breaks and stops the printing of the pattern. I even tried to print the value of b but understood that it won't work due to the scope limitations. Can someone please confirm me the value of final value of b here in this code.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly. --- Please read: [How to debug small programs (`https://ericlippert.com/`)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: A small note, but you don't need `System.out.println("")` you could just use `System.out.println()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the final iteration of the loop `b` is decremented from `0` to `-1` at which point the loop ends and `b` goes out of scope. We can demonstrate this by "hoisting" `b`. You could also eliminate the inner loop by using [`String.repeat(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)). Like,

```
int b;
for (b = 3; b >= 0; b--) {
    System.out.println("*".repeat(b + 1));
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Outputs

```
****
***
**
*
-1
```

Comment: Thank you for adding "hoisting" to my coding vocabulary.

Comment: @Bohemian [*How to Hoist a Sail*](https://youtu.be/YQTFaqRjk5o)

Comment: fYeah I know what "hoist" means (flags, sails etc). I've just never seen/heard it used in the context of code scope. It's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

`0` for (; ; )`

- **A** - set initial value (do it once before start)
- **B** - check condition to continue (do it before each iteration; even before the first one)
- **C** - set new value (do it after each iteration)

So your condition is `b >= 0`, indeed in case you do not have `brake`, so only one way to finish a loop is when `b < 0`.

---

**P.S.** Why don't you use normal iteration: from the `0` to the `b`. It should be more intuitive.

```java
public static void foo(int width) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width - i; j++)
            System.out.print('*');

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: `int n = 4; IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> "*".repeat(n - i)).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think this is too difficult to him

Comment: That's why I just made it a comment, instead of covering it in my answer. But it is nicely concise.